# How to Enable AMDGPU?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, fglrx, gpu-driver, amd-graphics

I didn't know that Ubuntu was using AMDGPU by default and I've installed fglrx. It's already removed now.

I want to reactivate AMDGPU, how can I do that?

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

[image: Graphics Card]

```
lsmod | grep amd
```

[image: AMDGPU]

Comment: You can give this a shot, although I don't think it fits your question exactly: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761091/ati-intel-hybrid-graphics-16-04-lts.

Comment: just check if this not already in use. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device/336427#336427

Comment: and also check that what driver is in use?  

`sudo lspci -v`

Comment: and then try this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#Configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics)

Answer (score 1):

If your graphics card is supported you may wish to consider AMDGPU-PRO. You can find the *latest* 16.60 version of the driver here [link] (http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx)

Comment: Your link is broken!

Comment: @George JMKõ edited his answer and fixed the broken link with an updated link to the latest version of AMDGPU-PRO (version 16.60) which is now out of beta.

Comment: This card is NOT supported.

Answer (score 1):

The opensource amdgpu driver is for GCN+ class hardware only.
Your GPU is a VLIW-based HD 5000 series that works with the radeon driver out of the box, and is NOT supported by the amdgpu driver.