# ATI/Intel hybrid graphics 16.04 LTS. DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer" output my intel card

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

As i read here [ATI/Intel hybrid graphics 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761091/ati-intel-hybrid-graphics-16-04-lts?rq=1) i can test my amd card using glxinfo and glmark2, but this output my intel card

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
> OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile

DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
> OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile

DRI_PRIME=1 glmark2
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
=======================================================
```

But lspci output that i have amd card

```
lspci | grep Display
> 01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
lspci | grep VGA
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

What should i do to make my AMD cark work well when i'm run smth like `DRI_PRIME=1 blender`

Comment: Is it a fresh install or an upgrade from some previous release of Ubuntu?