# I think my thermald-conf.xml is wrong

Tags: hp, intel, overheating, hp-pavilion, ivybridge

```
<Platform>
<Name>Generic X86 Laptop Device</Name>
<ProductName>EXAMPLE_SYSTEM</ProductName>
<Preference>QUIET</Preference>
<ThermalSensors>
    <ThermalSensor>

        <Type>TSKN</Type>
        <AsyncCapable>1</AsyncCapable>

    </ThermalSensor>
</ThermalSensors>
<ThermalZones>
    <ThermalZone>
        <Type>SKIN</Type>
        <TripPoints>
            <TripPoint>
                <SensorType>TSKN</SensorType>
                <Temperature>55000</Temperature>

                <type>passive</type>
                <ControlType>SEQUENTIAL</ControlType>
                <CoolingDevice>
                    <index>1</index>
                    <type>rapl_controller</type>
                    <influence> 100 </influence>
                    <SamplingPeriod> 16 </SamplingPeriod>
                </CoolingDevice>
                <CoolingDevice>
                    <index>2</index>
                    <type>intel_powerclamp</type>
                    <influence> 100 </influence>
                    <SamplingPeriod> 12 </SamplingPeriod>
                </CoolingDevice>
            </TripPoint>
        </TripPoints>
    </ThermalZone>
</ThermalZones>
```

This is my Thermald configuration file
inside

/sys/class/thermal/

i can see 5 cooling devices

for eg- cooling_device0 cooling_device1 till cooling_device 4
and 2 thermal_zone0 and thermal_zone1 file

i guess by seeing the thermal-conf.xml i am not using my cooling device and 
my laptop is always above 80 C and lags alot after 89 C

System specs

Hp pavilion g6 2320tx

Intel i5 ivybridge

4gb ram

can anyone please help me with this

Comment: What method did you use to install thermald?

Comment: Its preinstalled on u ubuntu 16.04 I guess

Comment: There is no path tag in the thermal sensor to the cooling devices , while I saw other conf files on internet , all were having path files

Comment: I don't think my fan is properly working in ubuntu because at high temp also it's at normal speed and CPU starts heating up and system lags

Comment: That's not your entire file is it?

Comment: No it's not the the entire file, do you want me to post the entire file ?

Comment: No, I just noticed that the default file includes more stuff and wanted to make sure all that stuff was still there. If you didn't change it it should be default.

Comment: So what should I do ? Because this conf file I think is not using the cooling devices I guess , so should I add the path to it and add every cooling device ?

Comment: Thermald doesn't usually do much until the system reaches high temps usually around 80C. I think it would be best to get the temp lower by other means.

Comment: Can you please specify some other means to do it ?

Comment: Well so far, none of my suggestions have worked. Hopefully, someone knows more than I do.

Comment: Well thank you for your effort sir , really appreciate it , would you recommend me to go for kubuntu ,  will it be helpful in my scenario?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you have amd graphics? Go to system settings, click on "software and updates", click on the "additional drivers" tab. Then, select the "proprietary"  driver listed as "tested". Then, reboot. I don't think Kubuntu would make a difference.

Comment: Yes I am using amd graphics but the proprietary drivers are discontinued in ubuntu 16.04 so what should you recommend ? Should I revert back to 14.04 ?

Comment: That may be an option. I see that 14.04 is recommended for those who need the proprietary driver. http://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx

Comment: Also, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/760879/amdgpu-with-hybrid-graphics-16-04?rq=1

Comment: So I guess I'll try to go back to 14.04 , anyways thank you soo very much sir for all the effort , it's because of you guyz that the ubuntu world is properly functioning :)